# Can I do some sort of authentication when dynamically loading modules via webpack?

Tags: javascript, authentication, webpack, dependencies, code-splitting

The prevailing pattern in single page app security seems to be:

1. User authenticates themselves
2. User gets a token
3. User makes api requests with the token

That's fine for limiting access to data, but in a lot of cases, code for UI that might have to do with another user seems to be present and can be accessed by changing some values via something like redux. That UI gives away information through certain menu options, request structure (ajax functions tied to things like buttons and forms), instructions, etc. In general, it seems like a good idea to hide that information if you can.

One solution is to split the app into user specific bundles and put each bundle behind an authenticated endpoint. The only problem I have with this solution is that you end up needing to reload a bunch of shared modules on login.

I'd prefer to dynamically load the modules by doing something like this (with webpack):

```
require.ensure(["./file1"], function() {
  // do things
});
```

I haven't dove into dynamically loading chunks too much so I'm not sure what endpoint is hit to load `./file1` or whether that's something you set up yourself, but theoretically I don't see any reason why you couldn't pass a token along and authenticate the user requesting `./file1`. Does anyone know how you would do that? Is it an idea worth pursuing, or is there some reason why I shouldn't want to do something like this?

Comment: The idea of "user specific bundles" sounds really inefficient, or at least unnecessarily hard to code. If you want sensitive user-specific data to be loaded in JS, why not use an authenticated AJAX call? Or just use a server-side templating engine (for user-specific markup)? Or both (i.e. Turbolinks)? Please clarify if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Part of my concern is that the frontend code for certain users is somewhat sensitive. What you're proposing is what most people seem to do, but it seems to have some drawbacks.

Creating separate bundles is trivial with webpack, as the different users have different entry points, which can be used to create separate bundles.

As to rendering things server side, I can't really do that with my current set up, as I'm not rendering data per page.

Comment: As long as you're using https (SSL) everything is encrypted anyway. Can you give me an example security flaw you're worried about?

Comment: Accidentally submitted my last comment before I was done, so maybe it'll be a little clearer now.

I'm concerned about allowing making certain bundles public. Most code splitting in webpack seems to rely on all of the chunks sitting in a public folder. I can secure data with that set up, but I would like to secure access to chunks as well.

Comment: You are correct that user specific bundles are inefficient. A vendor bundle that included vendor dependencies shared throughout the app would improve things, but there would still be shared code between different user bundles that could not be easily shared with that set up (at least I don't think they could be).

That's part of why I'd prefer to do code splitting. The only problem is that I don't like the idea of making the chunks public, which seems necessary.

Comment: I can't seem to edit my first comment: last sentence doesn't make any sense. I meant to say "I'm not rendering most pages on the server".

Comment: @GabeRogan More specific example: I'm worried about somebody loading `public/js/admin-code-chunk.js`, looking at what's in that frontend code and inferring things about admins (what they have access to, what their api interactions are like, etc).

Comment: So for the front-end you're looking for something like "if (isAdmin) loadAdminJsFile(yourUserToken)" and then serve the file only if the token is an admin token?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143628/discussion-between-gabe-rogan-and-didericis).

Comment: @GabeRogan Yeah